# Formating a query in ArcPy- why the error?

Tags: arcpy, query, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I have the following Select Layer By Attribute statement throwing a *000358 invalid expression* error using Python with ArcGIS 10.4.  The input feature layer is valid because I can select features using a select by location. When I try to remove some features from the selection the script fails.  There is an attribute in the feature dataset feature class called *returned* which stores data with a data type short.  Why is this line of code giving an error?

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("inFC_lyr2", "REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION", "\"returned\" = 1")
```

Per the suggestions below I added these lines to the code and got the same error.

```
inFC2 = r"Z:\Data\Planning\Buildings\Housing.gdb\AdressesStructures\Households"
sql_exp = """{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(inFC2, "returned"), 1)
print sql_exp
```

Interestingly sql_exp printed 
*returned = 1* to the screen.  Shouldn't that be "returned" = 1?

Comment: Why the backslashes? Try using Add Field Delimiters: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm

Comment: Because the query needs to have the quotes as delimiters because it is in a file geodatabase.  The backslashes guarantee the quotes.  That should pass "returned" = 1 to the tool.  That is how I have always done it.

Comment: Ok! My suggestion is to instead use Add Field Delimiters

Comment: What type of GDB are you using? Check field delimiters.

Comment: Understood, it is just that the use of the field delimiter guarantees the correct delimiter for the data type.  In my case I have a file geodatabase and the delimiter is a double quote.

Comment: you don't want the field name to be "returned", it should be returned =1 right?

Comment: sql_exp = "{0} = {1}".format("returned",1)

Comment: is your column a text? maybe it should be "1" as a string not a number...